# Limiting version numbers/copying old versions

Tags: sitecore-client, versions

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 deployed in PAAS and we want to limit number of items to up to 10 versions per item. There are multiple methods suggested

1) User Version Manager : In Previous Sitecore version we had various market place modules like  Version Manager etc but i see none of them is compatible with version

2) Use Rule Engine : Use Sitecore Rule engine as suggestted in this link

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/rules-engine-actions-to-remove-old-versions-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms.

Can somebody please suggest what is best way to do this or if  there any OOB way to limit the number of versions in Sitecore / any other market place module which works best for Siteore 9.0.2

Comment: Consider this answer https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/16227/95